# Add Print Item Custom Action To ECB Dropdown Menu

Tags: custom-actions, printing, ecb-menu

I am trying to make a print item on the ECB dropdown for a list item that allows printing of the item by clicking the menu item.

I can add the print item as below but how do I trigger a print when it is clicked?

```
<CustomAction Id="PrintListItem.ItemToolbar"
GroupId="PrintListItem"
RegistrationType="List"
RegistrationId="101"
Location="EditControlBlock"
Sequence="300"
Rights="ViewListItems"
Title="Print List Item"
ImageUrl ="/_layouts/Icon/PrintIcon.jpg">
<UrlAction Url="#"/>
</CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to print some item informations. You can develop a custom application page which receives the item and list IDs, build the html and print it. You can then pass it's url to the `UrlAction` parameter and open it in a modal dialog way.

Comment: If you judge that my answer isn't useful, then please provide us with a better one.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to included what goes in the custom application page?  Or is there a way to print the list item without the custom application page?

Comment: I've said that the custom master page will handle the HTML code that will be printed (Gridviews, Tables, ...). I'm unable to give more details since I don't know what information you want to print.

Comment: Well if the print menu item is going to be on the ECB menu dropdown then I want to print the list item that the menu item is on.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, could you explain what do you mean by "Print the list item" ?

Comment: The ECB is the EditControlBlock menu.  When you dropdown the menu on a list item in the list it shows this ECB menu.  My code above adds a "Print" menu to that dropdown menu. So when the user selects that "Print" menu option in the dropdown it is specific to that list item so should print the selected list item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21858/discussion-between-kgahbiche-and-motionpotion).

Comment: Sorry @motionpotion but I know exactly what's an ECB menu.
My question is, from the action on the ECB menu, what kind of information do you want to print ?
My thoughts are that after clicking on the action, I load a custom app page that gets the list and items IDs, loads all the kind of information that I want in the display form that I want, then launch a js script that prints the hole html result.